# Trying to better understand the Pullback Bundle

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles

I am currently trying to develop a better understanding of the pullback of a vector bundle (and more generally of fibre bundles), although I am struggling to develop nontrivial examples which can be easily visualised.

As an example, it seems to me that the pullback of the mobius strip (considered as a line bundle over $S^1$) by the map $f:\theta\mapsto2\theta$ should be the trivial bundle, although I am at a loss for how to prove this from the definition given,

$f^{-1}E = \{(n,e)\in N\times E \  \ | f(n) = \pi(e)\}$

With $f:N\to M$ the map we are pulling back over and $\pi:E\to M$ the bundle over $M$.

Also: In trying to get a better sense of the things, I turned to wikipedia and found the line
"It is illuminating to consider the pullback of the degree 2 map from the circle to itself over the degree 3 or 4 map from the circle to itself."
I am at a complete loss for what this means, although I suspect it could prove fruitful, since $S^1$ seems the best candidate for gaining some visual intuition as to what's going on.

Comment: As I see, the better way to understand the definition of pullback bundle is to look at the fibers $(f^*E)_{x}=\{x\}\times E_{f(x)}$ where $x\in N$. Also, when you want to get an isomorphism, try to see if you can do it at the level of fibers first..

Comment: Do you have a nice way to represent the mobius strip? If yes, at least you can some calculations.

Comment: @ArcticChar The simplest way to represent it I can think of is to introduce a second angle $\varphi$ to account for the twisting of the line bundle. In the mobius strip, it is given by $\varphi = \frac{\theta}{2}$ (as $\varphi$ will only have completed a half rotation in the time it takes to go around the circle), while in the pullback bundle, it would be $\varphi = \frac{f(\theta)}{2} = \frac{2\theta}{2} = \theta$, which would correspond to a full twist, which can be undone to give the trivial bundle.

Comment: @Flumpo that's completely correct..... so what is your question exactly?

Comment: @ArcticChar One thing that has me really confused is the fact that the definition I encountered seems rather broad, and that maps $f:\theta\mapsto r\theta$ seem to all be valid. If $r=n$, an integer, it seems pretty simple, trivial if n is even and the mobius strip if n is odd. If $r< 1$, my intuition is that this is essentially the same as $f:S^1\to\mathbb{R}$, and the resulting pullback should be trivial. However, I can't seem to figure out what to expect for any values of $r\in \mathbb{r}$ outside this.

Comment: @PtF Sorry, Sorry, I'm a little confused with that one. Shouldn't the base space of $E_1\times E_2$ be $M\times M$? For example, if $E_1 = M\times\mathbb{R}^n$ and $E_2 = M\times\mathbb{R}^m$ are trivial, wouldn't $E_1\times E_2 = (M\times\mathbb{R}^n)\times(M\times\mathbb{R}^m) \simeq (M\times M) \times (\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^m) = (M\times M)\times\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$?

Comment: Note that $\theta \mapsto r\theta$ is well-defined as a continuous function $\mathbb S^1 \to \mathbb S^1$ only when $r\in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: @ArcticChar Oh, ok, thanks. That makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Also, do you know what is meant in the sentence from wikipedia? Is the degree 2 map supposed to be the bundle, and the degree 3/4 map the function $f$?

Comment: I have to say I have no idea what they are trying to say in that paragraph. I am not even sure which circles are they referring to.

Comment: @Flumpo You're right. If $E_1\rightarrow M$ and $E_2\rightarrow M$ are vector bundles, considering the vector bundle $E_1\times E_2\rightarrow M\times M$ then $\Delta^* (E_1\times E_2)=E_1\oplus E_2$, where $\Delta: M\rightarrow M\times M$ is the diagonal map. The base of the bundle you're pulling back has to be the same as the codomain of the map you're using to perform the pullback.

Comment: @PtF Oh, yeah, I think I get how it works now, thanks.